# Pjsip - mini conference call (audio)

Tags: android, ios, voip, pjsip

May i create mini conference audio calls like:
A call B, A call C. then
1. A can receive sounds from B and C
2. B talks, then A and C will receive the sound also.
I think the ways to implement to redirect the sound or merge source.

Are there any ways to implement from react-native-pjsip ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for react-native-pjsip but I found the solution for **Android**.
What you need to do is you have to **transmit AudioMedia** of both ports.

eg.
When A -> B is in call and you want to process call for A -> C then once it's completed(A -> C call happened), you have to transmit AudioMedia of B -> C and C -> B.

```
private fun transmitAudio(audio1: AudioMedia?, audio2: AudioMedia?) {
        audio1?.startTransmit(audio2)
        audio2?.startTransmit(audio1)
    }
```

For Android, refer [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/pjsip-doc/media) link.